# How can electrically short these terminals?

Tags: microcontroller, short-circuit

Shorting red + white 1 moves the garage door up and shorting red + white 2 moves the garage door down, I’m using a micro controller but not sure how I can electrically short these terminals. [image: Garage motor with pins]

Comment: What voltage do you measure between the wires? AC or DC? If DC you can use transistors. If AC you can use relays which will probably still need a transistors to act as a middleman between relay and MCU.

Comment: That's what relays are for -- electronically controlled switches.

Comment: @DKNguyen I measured 16 volts and I strongly believe it’s DC, would 16 volts be too much for a TO-92 transistor?

Comment: TO-92 is just a physical package. It can be any silicon transistor inside.

Comment: Typical small general purpose transitors like BC547  2N3059  etc are not bothered by 18V.  when you measured it which terminal was positive ans which negative?  is there voltage between the two whites?  is there voltage between the two whites when you short either of the colours in?  if you measure the shorting current what  figure do you get?

Answer (score 1):

A 2 channel SPDT Relay Board, activated by 2 micro-controller outputs, could do that.

Should remote operation be required, a 2 channel SPDT RF relay board, with companion remote, could be used.